# How to convert iwork document into pdf using objective c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, osx-snow-leopard

please help in solving an issue.

I want to print iwork document but they are not getting printed directly using objective c.

As i can print PDF files easily using objective c.

so i want to covert the iwork documents(pages,keynote,numbers) to PDF.

Is there any way of converting the documents into PDF??

like any API or somethiing else which will convert iwork document into PDF.

Thanks.....

Comment: Pages contains convert to PDF, so why not to do that way?

Comment: This question couldn't be any more clear. It presents a legitimate problem.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't an "iWork API", if that's what you're looking for. You could probably drive the iWork applications using AppleScript to do this, and you can read more about how to call AppleScripts/send AppleEvents from Objective-C applications by looking [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ScriptableCocoaApplications).

Note: I have found sending AppleEvents from Objective-C to be non-trivial; I would recommend getting your script working natively (i.e. written in AppleScript) before embarking on writing Objective-C code to send the equivalent AppleEvents.

Comment: **Yes i am trying this thing also, but the problem I am able to convert the .pages file into pdf but for the numbers and keynote i am not able to do that, if you can guide me in solving this issue about how to convert these documents in PDF using applescript it would be a great for me...** @ipmcc